# addCategoryFilter() not working or working wrong

Tags: category, filter, category-attribute

I want the top sellers from magento store. I become the bestseller but when I want to using a category i get nothing. Here is my code I use:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setId($cat_id);
        $_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')     
                ->setStoreId($storeId)
                ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
                ->addOrderedQty()
                ->addCategoryFilter($category)
                ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', $visibility)
                ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')
                ->setPageSize($productCount)->load();
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')
                ->addVisibleFilterToCollection($_productCollection);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')
                ->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($_productCollection);
```

I didn't find the error in this code. Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

issue with

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setId($cat_id);
```

**should be use load function instead of setid and load() fucntion is loading category object of particular category**

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id);
```

Comment: Oh i've forgot to change this back to load() but it don't works with load also